# Subtract each value of a list Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, calculator, subtraction

I'm trying to build a simple calculator. I have done the addition part using sum function. However, I'm not able to achieve the same with subtraction. I want to subtract each value in the list from the value before it, i.e., if the list (user input) is [10,5,3], I want my output to be 10-5-3=2. Here's my code so far.

```
def calculate():
    input = raw_input("input: ")
    if "+" in input:
        sum_val = sum(map(float, input.split('+')))
        if sum_val.is_integer():
            print int(sum_val)
        else:
            print sum_val
    elif "-" in input:
        print map(float, input.split('-'))

calculate()
```

User input can be 10-5-3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = [10,5,3]    
s = reduce(lambda x, y: x - y, l)
```

s == 2

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
user_input = [10, 5, 3]

equation = '-'.join(map(str, user_input))

print(equation, '=', eval(equation))
```

Output -

```
10-5-3 = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line `map(float, input.split('-'))` with the following code,

```
import functools
import operator

l = map(float, input.split('-'))
r = functools.reduce(operator.sub, l)   # 3
```

Answer (score 1):

you need these two functions:

```
from operator import sub
from functools import reduce
reduce(sub, map(float, input.split('-')))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
l = [10,5,3]
if len(l) > 1:
   ans = l[0] - sum(l[1:])
else:
   ans = sum(l)
print(ans)
```

output: 2

Answer (score 0):

Other answers make use of standard functions, notably `functools.reduce`.

The following looks simpler to me, while it use only intention lists:

```
head, *tail = [10, 5, 3]
r = sum(-x for x in tail, head)
print(r)
```

Comment: This is wrong. The OP needs `10 - 5 - 3`, not `-10 - 5 -3`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could use a **Sentinel**. A sentinel basically allows you to keep track of an arbitrary condition in a loop. Addition works fine because your initial sum is 0 and you can just keep adding to increase that value. But with subtraction you need to initialize a sum variable with the first occurring integer in the list, at index 0.

*example:*

```
sum = 0
print_string = ""
sample_list = [10,5,3]
for i in range(len(sample_list)):
    if (i == 0):
        sum = sample_list[i]
    else:
        sum-=sample_list[i]

    if ((i+1) < len(sample_list)):
        print_string = print_string + str(sample_list[i]) + "-"

    # Now is time to finish it up
    print_string = print_string + "=" + str(sum)

    print(print_string)
```

*Output:*

```
10-5-3=2
```